# make div as wide as icon-card

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

As you can see, the transparent block in the middle is wider than the containing block. I tried to set left/right, margin-left/right and width, none of them changed the way the block looks.

[image]

HTML code:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-card ion-item no-lines> 
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x250"/>
      <button ion-button icon-only clear class="info-icon">
        <ion-icon name="information-circle"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <div class="dish-description">
        <h3>Descriptions go here. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</h3>
      </div>
      <ion-card-content>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</ion-list>
```

CSS:

```
ion-card-content {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color: #fff;
}

.info-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top:4%;
    right:5%;
}

.dish-description {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    height: 200px;
    width:50%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    text-align: center;
}

.dish-description h3 {
    color: #fff;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have `position: absolute`, margin no longer works. Try this

```
.dish-description {
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
    margin: 10px; //adjust as needed
    height: 200px;
    max-width:50%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Hard coding the margin will not work across different platforms. Is there any ionic variable we can use here?

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to do it ,
The trick is , you have to create the main container which holds the inner ion card.

We can use flex or div , For an instances, If youre making a responsive layout . 
I would suggest creating using percentage but that does not mean it will solve all issue, keep in mind that ionic framework does have different styling with different operating system . To overwrite ionic styling, there are few ways to it.Use debugging mode from your browser , it will help and save alot of try and error time.

To add on,
There are certain styling that is pre-generated , Like an example
, 
whatever you put inside "ion-item" will have a few classes appended to it , like md-inner-item and so on..

So , to answer your question, 
First try creating a main container , The div inside the ion-card, put a styling that has the max-width that is not more than the parent DOM. 
Example

```
<div class="mainContainer"> //put max-width  to 100% 
  <ion-card class="">
    <div class="dish-description"> //put max-width : 80%
    <h3>Descriptions go here. bla </h3>
  </div>
  <ion-card>
  </ion-card>

</div>
```

I hope this helps. :)